# mktemp creates file in pwd rather than in /tmp

Tags: files, gnu, tmp, mktemp

Previously mktemp used to create files in `/tmp`. Today I noticed that mktemp is creating file in  `$PWD` rather than in `/tmp`?

#### Did I change something inadvertently? Any suggestions to fix this?

---

Note:

I am able to do: `ls /tmp`

```
$ mktemp --version
mktemp (GNU coreutils) 8.30
```

```
$ echo $TMPDIR

$
```

Comment: `echo "$TMPDIR"`

Comment: What's the value of `$TMPDIR` when `mktemp` is used in your code or on the command line?

Comment: `$ echo $TMPDIR` is blank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the GNU Coreutils implementation, there is a difference depending on whether an explicit `TEMPLATE` is provided on the command line or not. As per the man page:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>       mktemp [OPTION]... [TEMPLATE]
> ```

> ```
> If TEMPLATE is not specified, use `tmp.XXXXXXXXXX`, and `--tmpdir` is implied.
> ```

(note the `--tmpdir is implied`); where

> ```
>    -p DIR, --tmpdir[=DIR]
>           interpret TEMPLATE relative to DIR; if DIR is not specified, use $TMPDIR 
>           if set, else /tmp.
> ```

So

```
$ mktemp foo.XXX
foo.eWT
```

uses the current directory, whereas plain

```
$ mktemp
/tmp/tmp.hrY7qNWWty
```

defaults to `/tmp` (since `--tmpdir` is implied, but no `$TMPDIR` set).